# Custom Dialog that close fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, dialog

User makes registration. I have made this process in viewpager2. While user is registaring, he can exit. There is appropriates button for this. When he clicks on this, he will receive a dialog, that ask him "Are you sure??". I want it to have custom view. So, I have created kotlin class for my dialog. On clicking on button cancel, dialog will dismiss. On clicking on button yes fragment with viewpager2 will close and he will come to home fragment for login. I have problems with last. Here is my dialog class:

```
class AlertInterruptRegistration(context: Context) : Dialog(context){

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        setContentView(R.layout.alert_interrupt_registration)

        noButtonAIR.setOnClickListener{
            this.dismiss()
        }
        yesButtonAIR.setOnClickListener{
            SignUpFragment().closeThisFragment()
            this.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is method closeThisFragment:

```
fun closeThisFragment() {
    (activity as SignActivity).closeFragment()
}
```

Here is closeFragment in SignActivity:

```
fun closeFragment() {
    super.onBackPressed()
}
```

- *I have overridden onBackPressed in SignActivity so I made another
  method for this.*

When I click on YES button, here is an error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
       Process: com.samapps.myjami.dev, PID: 23417
       kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.samapps.myjami.ui.activities.sign.SignActivity
            at com.samapps.myjami.ui.fragments.signup.SignUpFragment.closeThisFragment(SignUpFragment.kt:57)
            at com.samapps.myjami.ui.fragments.signup.alertstopregistr.AlertInterruptRegistration$onCreate$2.onClick(AlertInterruptRegistration.kt:22)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22465)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:933)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

- *SignUpFragment.kt:57 is line with closeThisFragment method and AlertInterruptRegistration.kt:22 is line with yesButtonOnClickListener method*

**How can I close fragment by clicking yes button in dialog?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come up with just restart my activity like this:

```
class AlertInterruptRegistration(context: Context, val activity: Activity) : Dialog(context) {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.alert_interrupt_registration)

        noButtonAIR.setOnClickListener {
            this.dismiss()
        }

        yesButtonAIR.setOnClickListener {
            this.dismiss()
            activity.finish()
            activity.startActivity(Intent(activity, SignActivity::class.java))
        }
    }
}
```

And calling my dialog:

```
val a = AlertInterruptRegistration(context!!, activity!!)
a.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach without your fragment dependency could be the following

First create an interface as below

```
interface DialogListener {
   fun closeThisFragment()
}
```

Make `SignInActivity` implement `DialogListener`

```
SignActivity: DialogListener
```

Override `closeThisFragment` method as below

```
override fun closeFragment() {
    super.onBackPressed()
}
```

And finally `AlertInterruptRegistration` dialog add the following instruction

```
 yesButtonAIR.setOnClickListener{
        if(context is DialogListener){
             context.closeThisFragment()
         }
        this.dismiss()
    }
```

The advantage of using this approach is that your dialog is decoupled from `SignUpFragment` or any other fragment.

Comment: There is error on **context**.closeThisFragment(). It says Smart cast to 'DialogListener' is impossible , because 'context' is a property that has open or custom getter