# Visibilty gone layout of custom dialog from another function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, dialog, customdialog

I have a custom dialog in kotlin fragment which have 2 button and a progress bar in fuction `submitSpk()`

```
class RincianPembelianFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment(), BlockingStep {
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_spk_rincian_bayar, container, false)

    //initialize your UI

    return v
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    activity?.supportFragmentManager?.popBackStack(null, androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
    setContext(activity!!.applicationContext) 
}
fun submitSpks (){
        val inflater = context?.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context!!)

        val dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_signature, null)
        builder.setView(dialogView)
        builder.setTitle("Tanda Tangan Pembeli")
        //builder.show()
        builder.setCancelable(false)
        dialogView.clear.setOnClickListener {
            dialogView.signature_view.clearCanvas()
        }

        dialogView.save.setOnClickListener {
            submitTtd() // or some fuction else
            dialogView.save.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            dialogView.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        builder.setNegativeButton(""){ dialog: DialogInterface?, which: Int ->

        }

        builder.show()

}

fun submitTtd(){
    // here there will be a crud transaction and visible/invisible button save
}
}
```

my custom dialog is look like this [image: layout]

i want to visibility gone the button save `dialogView.save.visibility = View.VISIBLE` from another fuction e.g `saveTtd()`
how can i do this? i have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60870523/custom-dialog-that-close-fragment) but my dialog can't show.. anyone can help me? Thanks before

Comment: try passing dialogView binding to saveTtd() function as parameter and use it like saveTtd(dialogView)

Comment: can you show me the code please? @MaulikTogadiya

Comment: let me first confirm what is your use case ?
like the first dialog will be visible as like you shared image and on click of save button you want to hide that save button right?

Comment: yes, on click of save button i will call submitTtd() fuction and in submitTtd() i will hide that save button @MaulikTogadiya

Comment: Okay but why you just don't hide in from save button click and then call submitTtd() ?

Comment: Can you post your full fragment code?

Comment: because in submitTtd there will be some code (CRUD) which is rather long, and if the transaction fails it will show/hide the save button, and maybe there are several other functions which will be called on onclick of save button. but i only took part of the code to display on stackoverflow @MaulikTogadiya

Comment: i have edited my fragment in the question @LucaPizzini

Comment: Yes you can follow LucaPizini 's anwer or can pass dialogView to fun submitTtd()  as fun submitTtd(dialogView) and use it instend decleraring it in  gloable,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing the `dialogView` in a global variable should do the job.
Also, call the `build()` method on the `AlertDialog.Builder` instance before showing the dialog:

```
class RincianPembelianFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment(), BlockingStep {

    private lateinit var dialogView: View

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_spk_rincian_bayar, container, false)    
        //initialize your dialog view
        dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_signature, null)
        return v
    }
    
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        activity?.supportFragmentManager?.popBackStack(null, androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
        setContext(activity!!.applicationContext) 
    }

    fun submitSpks() {
        // Using requireContext() is suggested
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
    
        builder.setView(dialogView)
        builder.setTitle("Tanda Tangan Pembeli")
        builder.setCancelable(false)
        dialogView.clear.setOnClickListener {
            dialogView.signature_view.clearCanvas()
        }
    
        dialogView.save.setOnClickListener {
            submitTtd() // or some fuction else
        }
    
        builder.setNegativeButton(""){ dialog: DialogInterface?, which: Int ->
    
        }
    
        // Build the dialog builder before showing it 
        val dialog = builder.build()
        dialog.show()
    }
    
    fun submitTtd(){
        // here there will be a crud transaction and visible/invisible button save
        dialogView.save.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        dialogView.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```